# distinct() method for unique strings in a list C#

Tags: c#, list, distinct

i have a question regarding the method distinct() in C#.
I have a string List.

```
List <string> stringtxt = stringtxt.distinct().ToList();
```

For example to strings in my stringtxt List are:

```
"A"
"B"
"C"
"B"
"E"
```

How can i implement this, that i only get the Output "A" "B" "C" "E". Witout the use of the Interface "IEquatable " or any HashCodes.
I used a foreach loop to solve this.

```
foreach(var stringitem in stringtxt)
{
    tb.text = stringitem;
}
```

But I am not sure if that is the best way to solve this.

---

From the comment below:

I am sorry i am trying to ask the question understandable :D Again this i my code:

```
List<string> stringvalues = new List<string>(); 
stringvalues.Add("A"); 
stringvalues.Add("ccc"); 
stingvalues.Add("B"); 
stingvalues.Add("B"); 
stingvalues.Add("E"); 
stringvalues.Add("hello"); 
List<string> stringtxt = stringvalues.Distinct().ToList(); 

//Output 
A,ccc,B,E,hello
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - after fixing the typo, your code shouldn't produce any duplicates anyway, as `Distinct()` only returns distinct values. It's not clear how the textbox is relevant, or how you're declaring `stringtxt` and using `stringtxt` in its initializer...

Comment: Not clear. `List <string> stringtxt = stringtxt.Distinct().ToList();` is circular and won't compile. So what is your input like, and what didn't work?

Comment: You cannot declare a variable and use it as a source in the same statement: `List <string> stringtxt = stringtxt....`

Comment: stringtxt.Select(x=>x).distinct().ToList();

Comment: Do you mean something like `stringtxt = new string(stringtxt.Distinct().ToArray());` ?

Comment: Oh sorry, i made a typo, i mean that `List <string> stringtxt = stringvalues.Distinct().toList()` and **stringvalues** is also a string List and this list as the content of the string like "A,B,B,ccc,C,E,B" i only want the unique values like "A,B,ccc,C,E"

Comment: Then use the _edit_ link. Also read the MCVE link that Jon posted.

Comment: @mrleo as you can see from [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DjMC1G), this works perfectly well. As has been said, you need a [mcve].

Comment: `List<string> result = stringvalues.Distinct().ToList();` will work perfectly,  so whats your problem?

Comment: I am sorry i am trying to ask the question understandable :D Again this i my code:
           `List<string> stringvalues = new List<string>();

            stringvalues.Add("A");
            stringvalues.Add("ccc");
            stingvalues.Add("B");
            stingvalues.Add("B");
            stingvalues.Add("E");
            stringvalues.Add("hello");


            List<string> stringtxt = stringvalues.Distinct().ToList();`

            //Output
            A,ccc,B,E,hello

Comment: @mrleo is this output desired output that you want? Or you want something else?

Comment: no, that is the output i want @SeM

Comment: @mrleo So what's a problem? here is result -> https://dotnetfiddle.net/HHw6Mp

Answer (score 1):

I see that you just need to put the distinct list back to string? Then you just need the last line below:

```
List<string> stringtxt = new List<string>()
{
    "A",
    "B",
    "C",
    "B",
    "E"
};
stringtxt = stringtxt .Distinct().ToList(); // avoid redeclaring stringtxt as List<string>
// combine the stringlist into a string with , separator
string output = string.Join(",", distinctStringList );
```

Comment: thank you @kurakura88 , but i cant use the split function because i have a string List

Answer (score 0):

Create a `hashtable`, go through all your strings with a `foreach` and try to add it. If it fails, ignore the error.
At the end, just print all the elements in your hashtable.

For example :

```
    Hashtable hash= new Hashtable();
    foreach (var s in your_list)
    {

      try
      {
          hash.Add(s, s);
      }
      catch
      {
          // will happen if exists
      }
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much, i have done this with a hashtable, too and i got the same result. So for uniqueness i can use the method distinct() or i can implement a hashtable right :) ?

Comment: yep. i'll use distinct, which does the work for you, but if you want to do it yourself, a hashtable or a dictionary would do nicely. you could do it with a list, but the running time will suffer (not on your toy list of 100 items, but the time will be exponential.